# executing terminal commands in Applescript

Tags: applescript

I executed the terrminal commnand "system_profiler SPApplicationsDataType" in AppleScript for to obtain installed app in MAC, I need to parse the output, Pls explain how to achieve it either thru Apple script or Python.

Comment: Have you found the answer useful? You have not accepted any answers on any of your questions. You should learn to contribute back to SO.

Answer (score 0):

**In Python you can use subprocess -**

http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

Specifically, the `check_output` method: http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

So you would just use:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(["system_profiler", "SPApplicationsDataType"])
print output # or do something else with it
```

Your command will be broken into an array, one element for each of your arguments.

**In Applescript you could do something like:**

```
set textReturned to (do shell script "system_profiler SPApplicationsDataType")

tell application "TextEdit"
    activate
    make new document at the front
    set the text of the front document to textReturned
end tell
```

This will run the command and dump the output to TextEdit.

Comment: thanks for the reply its working fine.. do you have any idea on how to automate the process of installing an downloaded app using AppleScript or Python?? If so pls suggest me.

Comment: You will need to do some further research on that. :) (Also, if the answer is correct, then do accept it as correct!)